# MySQL max_connections setting - per client or global?

Tags: mysql, max-connections

So I just need to clear this up.

For a test, I set `max_connections=10` in `my.cnf`.

I then ran 10 scripts concurrently that each take over 20 seconds to finish.

I monitored my threads and noticed that when I hit 10 the `Too many connections` error fired.

That's fine, but I'm only one person. If there were multiple clients connected would they have 10 connected threads each, or between them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) is a global setting.

You are limited to a total of 10 connections, *no matter how many users are authenticating*.

If you want to limit a specific user, such as `myuser@localhost`, to 10 connections, you would specify that with the GRANT command

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `myuser@localhost` MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 10;
```

or hack it in like this

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET max_user_connections = 10
WHERE user='myuser' AND host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you want 200 connections total, just set [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) to 200.

You don't even have to restart mysqld.

Just do the following

STEP 01 : Add `max_connections=200` to `my.cnf` under `[mysqld]` group header

STEP 02 : Login as `root@localhost` and run `SET GLOBAL max_connections=200;`